# Force p:databale to fill the container without using style="width: 100%"

Tags: css, primefaces

I want to make a `p:datatable` fill its container. But I want to keep `style="width: auto"`. Otherwise table will not display properly in small browser windows (`mobile`). Is there a way to do this?

I am using following as a workaround.

```
.ab-my-table table.ui-responsive.ui-table {
       width: auto;
 }

/* Use 100% width for  table in large screens to get a nicer look */
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
   .ab-my-table table.ui-responsive.ui-table {
       width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi please provide some code to help us to understand the problem ?!?

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this is a simple p:dataTable. I haven't use any special customization etc. By default the table width is auto. So for example if page width in 1800px, table with may be 800px when the values inside table columns are not long. In this case there is a empty space and it make the page ugly. To prevent that I can use style="width : 100%". But if I used that, when the page is viewed in smaller screens table does not format properly. Because widths are no longer adjusted automatically.

Comment: did you tryed to use **datatable responsive** you learn about that here : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/responsive.xhtml

Comment: Yes. This is a responsive table.